# Inverting binary tree (recursive)

Tags: python, binary-tree

I can't figure out how to output a reversed binary tree. This is what I've come up so far + my pseudo code.

**Creating a binary tree**

```
#Creating the binary tree
from binarytree import build
from binarytree import tree
   
# List of nodes 
nodes =[4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6, 9] 
  
# Builidng the binary tree 
binary_tree = build(nodes) 
print('Binary tree from example :\n ', 
      binary_tree) 
  
# Getting list of nodes from 
# binarytree 
print('\nList from binary tree :',  
      binary_tree.values)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Pseudo code:**

```
#def invert_tree(nodes, root)

#Stop recursion if tree is empty

#swap left subtree with right subtree

#invert left subtree

#invert right subtree
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-nodes-binary-tree-every-kth-level/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found an answer**

```
nodes = [[4], [7, 2], [1, 3, 6, 9]]
```

#### **Recursive**

```
newlist1 = []
def reverse_tree(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    newlist1.append(lst.pop(0)[::-1])
    reverse_tree(lst)

reverse_tree(nodes)

print(newlist1)
```

**Output:**

```
[[4], [2, 7], [9, 6, 3, 1]]
```

#### **Using list comprehension**

```
#ListComprehension
newlist2 = [x[::-1] for x in nodes]
print(newlist2)
```

**Output:**

```
[[4], [2, 7], [9, 6, 3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your question isn't clear;

From what I understood:

To print the nodes of an inverted tree:
    Try Level order traversal, more precisely you can use the BFS method.
```

OR: If you want to invert a Binary tree; My approach (given the root node of the tree):

```
def invert_tree(self, root):
    if root:
        temp=root.left
        root.left = self.invert_tree(root.right)
        root.right = self.inver_tree(temp)
        return root
```

Since, every node in the tree in visited once, the time complexity is O(n).

Comment: You're right. I could have been more precise. Just one question isn't my first solution a BFS (level by level) traversal?

There I treated a python list (newlist1) as a stack with the pop() and append() method and went from the root level to the second level.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Definition for a binary tree node.
     * public class TreeNode {
     *     int val;
     *     TreeNode left;
     *     TreeNode right;
     *     TreeNode() {}
     *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
     *         this.val = val;
     *         this.left = left;
     *         this.right = right;
     *     }
     * }
     */
     //recursion problem, swap every left with the right node in postorder 
     class Solution {
          public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
               if (root == null) return null;
               if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                    return root;
               }
               invertTree(root.left);
               invertTree(root.right);
               TreeNode temp = root.left;
               root.left = root.right;
               root.right = temp;
               return root;
          }
     }
```

Try this code using Java format at Leetcode you will pass..

Comment: Please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

TreeNode* Invert(TreeNode* tree) {

```
if(tree == NULL) return NULL;

TreeNode* temp;
temp = tree->left;
tree->left = tree->right;
tree->right = temp;

Invert(tree->left);
Invert(tree->right);
return tree;
```

}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31385002)